# How do I rank the column on percentile and remove the bottom 0.1% percentile data from a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

At work I need to remove the bottom 0.1% data aka I only need data with percentile rank =< .99.
How can I rank the column I want to calculate percentile on where it gives me percentile rank from .01 to .99 so that I can eliminate the data I don't want?

The column I want to get the percentile for also needs to be partitioned by another column. There are X values in one column, which has Y values each which I want the percentile for.

I used the `percent_rank` function, but it doesn't give out accurate results. The examples on the internet show it'll rank the data from 0 to 1 but while mine does start at 0 it ends at .57 for one column and .93 for another column and so on, but never goes till .99 or 1.
I wrote `percent_rank() over (partition by ColX order by ColY)`. Am I missing something here? If this works properly, it's exactly what I am looking for.

I also tried using the functions shown [here](https://leafo.net/guides/postgresql-calculating-percentile.html), but I didn't quite understand what's happening with the `ntile` function and the `generate_series` returned an error basically saying that the numbers in the brackets `(0.01, 1, 0.01)` are out of range. The host cloud tool my company uses doesn't work with Postgres, like Postgres now accepts `-1` indexing, but the tool we use doesn't. It still says indexing needs to be a positive number. So I don't exactly know why the error is occuring.

I feel like I am missing something obvious here, there is a very simple function which will do the work but I can't just find it.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: I tried adding tables initially but couldn't figure it out then and by the time I did, I figured the solution and forgot to ever update anything here. If the table is still needed, please tell me, I'll add it.

Comment: please make a dbfiddle and add the tables as text we will edit xou text, so don't worry about it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like values in ColY column are not unique inside ColX group.

In this case last records in each group share the same percent rank

In example below ident is unique inside group

**Question without unique "order by"**

```
select ident, ColX, ColY, percent_rank() over (partition by ColX order by ColY) from table
```

Result

| ident | ColX | ColY | percent_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 0.5 |

**Question with unique "order by"**

```
select ident, ColX, ColY, percent_rank() over (partition by ColX order by ColY, ident) from table
```

Result

| ident | ColX | ColY | percent_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: The percent_rank is the ideal function, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. It didn't give accurate percentile ranks (as I have already mentioned in my question). I figured out the solution though, I could do the next step of my problem without needing to rank every value's percentile.